# how can a parent directive add behavior to child directives in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, directive

I am trying to create a toolbar and toolbaritem directives. Basically toolbar is a container and holds toolbaritems(buttons in this case). The information about the number of toolbaritems, text on each item and their behavior upon click are external to toolbaritem directive and are associated using a model. I'm able to set the text on the toolbaritem, but unable to add behavior dynamically. Below is the code:

### index.html

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myActionCtrl">
<action-toolbar actions="actionItems"></action-toolbar>
</body>
```

### Controller.js

```
app.controller('myActionCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
var actionItems = [{ "name": "Post", "action": "Post()" }, 
                   { "name": "Recall", "action": "Recall()" },
                   { "name": "Signoff", "action": "Signoff()" }, 
                   { "name": "Attach", "action": "Attach()" }
                  ];
$scope.actionItems = actionItems;
$scope.Post = function () { alert('Post clicked'); }
$scope.Recall = function () { alert('Recall clicked'); }
$scope.Signoff = function () { alert('Signoff clicked'); }
$scope.Attach = function () { alert('Attach clicked'); }
}]);
```

### directive.js

```
app.directive('actionToolbar', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {actions:'='},
    template: '<div ng-repeat="item in actions">'+
                        '<action-item name={{item.name}} action={{item.action}}>         </action-item>' + '</div>'
  };

});


app.directive('actionItem', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{name:'@',action:'@'}, //will discuss on this below
    template: "<button>{{name}}</button>",
    link: function (scope, element) {
        element.bind('click', scope.action);
    }
  }
});
```

With the above code, it gives me an error that "Undefined is not a function". I assume this because scope.action is read as a string in the actionItem isolated scope. 
With this error, tried modifying the isolatedscope param to scope: `{name:'@',action:'&'}`, but then it complaints

```
[$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'item.action' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{item.action}}] starting at [item.action}}]
```

Comment: @ binds the value of an attribute(which is always a string) to a scope property. It'll obviously never be a function. I think what you want to do is `action="item.action"` in actionToolbar, and `action: '='` in actionItem - this will bind `scope.action` in actionToolbar to the expression `"item.action"`, which creates a two-way data binding between `item.action` from the ng-repeat and `action` in actionToolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a reason to put your Post, Recall, Signoff, and Attach functions on the scope, don't.  The objects in your actionItems array can store direct references to those functions like this

```
app.controller('myActionCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
var actionItems = [{ "name": "Post", "action": Post }, 
                   { "name": "Recall", "action": Recall },
                   { "name": "Signoff", "action": Signoff }, 
                   { "name": "Attach", "action": Attach }
                  ];
$scope.actionItems = actionItems;
function Post () { alert('Post clicked'); }
function Recall () { alert('Recall clicked'); }
function Signoff () { alert('Signoff clicked'); }
function Attach () { alert('Attach clicked'); }
}]);
```

Your action attribute on your toolbar directive should be an expression that will invoke the function you want to invoke like this

```
app.directive('actionToolbar', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {actions:'='},
    template: '<div ng-repeat="item in actions">'+
    '<action-item name={{item.name}} action="item.action()">' +
    '</action-item>' + 
    '</div>'
  };
});
```

Then in your actionItem directive you can bind to that expression in your isolate scope object with the & strategy, and set that function as a callback function in your linking function like this

```
app.directive('actionItem', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
        name:'@',
        action:'&'
    }, 
    template: "<button>{{name}}</button>",
    link: function (scope, element) {
        element.bind('click', scope.action)
    }
  }
});
```

Working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/r9rve69p/

Comment: Appreciate your reply. The solution works for my scenario. On your point as not associate the functions to scope, can you explain the downsides?

Comment: If you put functions/objects on your scope object and don't end up using them that makes your code confusing.  If you wanted to do something like ng-click="myFunction()" then it would make sense to put the myFunction function on your scope object, in your case you have a collection that your passing in to your actionToolbar directive so it wouldn't be clean to pass many functions into that directive through the template, if that makes sense.  Don't forget to accept answers if you feel they answered your question

Comment: In your example, you have considered action value in actionItems json object without quotes { "name": "Post", "action": Post }. (Post without quotes); this doesn't seem to work when the action value is in quotes. Can you suggest how to go about it as in my scenario the json data always has values in quotes?

Comment: If you have a collection of items and you need to associate a function to each item so that function can be used for the item in a generic directive you could loop over your items and attach the function to each one before you pass the collection in to your directive, like this http://jsfiddle.net/hr7f2dtq/ But maybe you should rethink whats going on, maybe the directive can define the functions instead of your controller and it can invoke the correct function depending on the contents of the items like this http://jsfiddle.net/a7vjsaa1/1/